# What exactly is Touhou Kinema-kan?

Tags: touhou-project

I see a lot of unofficial anime-style Touhou opening and ending videos with something like "Touhou Anime Kinema-kan" mentioned in the title or description. For example:

- [Touhou Anime Motion Picture ~Second Curtain~ 2nd PV 【東方】](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htOqsmrz_Eo)
- [Touhou Hana Kagura【Anime Motion Picture 2nd Curtain #2】【東方】【HQ】](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tq29WcecvVY)
- [Touhou Anime Kinema-kan - "東方白昼夢" ToHo Daydream(FULL)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxCMsS3zUv0)

But I can't find a good description or explanation of what exactly Touhou Anime Kinema-kan is. What does Kinema-kan mean? What does it refer to? And what does 2nd Curtain refer to? Is there a 1st Curtain, 3rd Curtain, and so on?

All I can gleam from the video descriptions is that it seems to be something that was released at Comiket or Reitaisai, but I don't know much beyond that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Touhou Kinema Kan (東方活動写真館)** is both the name of a defunct doujin circle and the series of animated music videos they produced in the years 2009-2011.

Below is the list of their works in chronological order:

- 東方活動写真館
- 東方活動写真館～第二幕～
- 橙の幻想郷音頭
- 東方恋隣童-Toho kourindo-
- 東方白昼夢
- 東方活動写真館～終幕～

[*Kinema (キネマ)*](https://jisho.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&keyword=%E3%82%AD%E3%83%8D%E3%83%9E) is cinema, and [*kan (館)*](https://jisho.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&keyword=%E9%A4%A8) is hall, so *Kinema Kan (活動写真館)* is cinema hall. The kanji [*活動写真 (katsudou shashin)*](https://jisho.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&keyword=%E6%B4%BB%E5%8B%95%E5%86%99%E7%9C%9F) is a retro word for cinema, used mainly in the Meiji and Taishō period.

Curtain is a mistranslation of [*幕 (maku)*](https://jisho.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&keyword=%E5%B9%95), which in this context means an act, a unit of a theater work. The first act is 東方活動写真館, followed by the second act 東方活動写真館～第二幕～ and the final act 東方活動写真館～終幕～, which is a compilation of all the previous works of the doujin circle in one disc.

#### References

- [Official Touhou Kinema Kan website [archived]](https://web.archive.org/web/20121125022616/http://www.tohokinemakan.jp/)
- [List of Touhou Kinema Kan's works [archived]](https://web.archive.org/web/20120116094335/http://tohokinemakan.jp:80/production.html)